# How to merge multiple columns into two by power query?

Tags: microsoft-excel

There is a table that consists of several pairs of columns.
It's basically the size breakdown of a product and its corresponding quantity.
How can I sum up the quantity of the same size and merge them together?
Now I use the copy and paste method to gather up all the information in the first two columns
and then select the first column and remove the duplicates and transpose the data set from column to row and finally fill in the formula sumifs to add up the number for each size. But I find it a bit inconvenient when the data is too big.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You've posted two screenshots, but it's not clear how exactly transformation should happen. Please explain.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.
I want the table in the first screenshot to be transformed into the table in the second screenshot.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Answer (score 1):

First create a query on the source table.
[image]

Use Add Column>Index Column. Then drag the column to the left of the query (not essential, but better!):
[image]

Then select the index column and use Transform>Any Column>Unpivot Columns>Unpivot other columns:
[image]

This will put each column header in the Attribute column.

Select the attribute column and use Transform>Text Column>Split Column>By Delimiter using an underscore as the delimiter:
[image]

You should now have something like this:
[image]

Now expand the Queries list on the left hand side, right click the query name and Duplicate the query.

Filter the first query on Attribute.1=TS.

Filter the duplicate on Attribute.1=QTY.

Now use Home>Combine>Merge Queries>Merge Queries as New, configured like this:
[image]

Expand the column list of the duplicate table in the merge result  by clicking the double-arrow. Retain only the value field:

[image]

Select the Value field from the original table, which is actually the TS value and use Home>Transform>Group By, configured like this:
[image]

The net result is the sum of the quantity by unique TS value.
[image]

You can now use Home>Close & Load to put the data back into the workbook.

Comment: It works!! Thanks a lot.